# Select upload history from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, dense-rank, partition-by

I have a table contains a list of factories (factory Id and factory names)

```
Factory ID    Factory Name
1001          Factory1
1002          Factory2
1003          Factory3
```

User will upload the some data into a history table for each factory, each month. And the existing factory data for the same month will be override by different user as well. Hence the history table will look like below.

```
Factory ID   Month UploadedValue UploadedBy UploadedOn
1001         01    250           User1      29.11.2016 07:28 PM
1002         01    102.12        User1      29.11.2016 07:28 PM
1001         01    400           User2      30.11.2016 12.00 PM
```

Now, I need to generate a report for each factory and each month, which is latest upload (who uploaded and when uploaded) and if there is no uploads then it should be shown as 'No upload'. This will look something below.

```
   Factory ID    Factory Name   Month   Last Upload by   Last Upload on
    1001          Factory1       01      User2            30.11.2016 12.00 PM
    1002          Factory2       01      User1            29.11.2016 07:28 PM
    1003          Factory3       01      Not Uploaded     Not Uploaded
```

Kindly help to get this. I tried with analytic function. but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`RANK()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions155.htm) function. Assuming the tables are `FAC` and `FAC_HIST`, the code mighe be as follows

```
SELECT fid, fname, month, last_uploaded_by, last_uploaded_on
  FROM ( select fh.fid fid
              , fh.fname fname
              , COALESCE(fd.month, 1) month
              , COALESCE(RANK() FIRST OVER (PARTITION BY fd.fid, fd.month 
                                                ORDER BY fd.last_uploaded_on DESC)
                         , -1) rnk
              , COALESCE(fd.uploaded_by, 'not uploaded') last_uploaded_by
              , COALESCE(fd.last_uploaded_on, 'not uploaded') last_uploaded_on
           FROM fac fh
           LEFT OUTER JOIN fac_hist fd
             ON fh.fid = fd.fid
                )
 WHERE rnk <= 1;
```

Comment: `DENSE_RANK()` will be fine in this exact situation, but it provides unnecessary functionality (filling in the gaps between ranks), which obscures what's being requested. `RANK()` does the job without the (minor) obfuscation. Also, please start using the standard JOIN syntax - it's been around for over 25 years and should really be standard now, especially is it makes your code more portable. Lastly please get used to using  `COALESCE()` instead of `NVL()`, this is also the standard so makes your code more portable but it doesn't implicitly convert, which reduces the chance of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Ben. In my company we're still using these syntaxes, so didn't know about the standardisations. Will read about these. Meanwhile, can you help editing this answer to be in line with what you are suggesting? Much appreciated.

Comment: I see COALESCE is exact in syntax with NVL! Thanks for the update

Comment: @RogueCoder - `nvl()` is older (introduced by Oracle a long time ago) and it is not optimized the way `coalesce()` is. Especially when the second argument is complicated and requires a lot of processing, this may be important. `coalesce()` calculates the second argument only when it is actually needed (when the first argument is `null`) while `nvl()` does not use this "short-circuit evaluation". In addition, `coalesce()` is standard in SQL, `nvl()` is not. Code using the former is more portable. So, two reasons to use the former!

Answer (score 0):

To pick up just the most recent update for each factory in each month, you can `group by factory_id` and `month` in the "updates" table, and select `max(updatedon)`. For the other columns you can use `keep (dense_rank last...)`. All of this is aggregate functions (rather than analytical) - and you don't do more work than needed.

The other part of the query is data densification. In more recent versions of Oracle, this can be done with "partition outer join" (Google to read more about this topic). I added a second "month" to the input data to fully illustrate the concept (see the Output as well). Note - I didn't bother with `'Not Uploaded'` instead of `null` - if really needed, one can wrap all values within `coalesce()` to replace `null` with that text, but I don't see what it adds. `null` conveys exactly the same information.

```
with
     factories ( factory_id, factory_name ) as (
       select 1001, 'Factory1' from dual union all
       select 1002, 'Factory2' from dual union all
       select 1003, 'Factory3' from dual
     ),
     updates ( factory_id, month, uploadedvalue, uploadedby, uploadedon ) as (
       select 1001, '01', 250   , 'User1', to_date('29.11.2016 07:28 PM', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
       select 1002, '01', 102.12, 'User1', to_date('29.11.2016 07:28 PM', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi AM') from dual union all
       select 1001, '01', 400   , 'User2', to_date('30.11.2016 12.00 PM', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi AM') from dual
     ),
     months ( month ) as (
       select '01' from dual union all
       select '02' from dual
     )
select fm.factory_id, fm.factory_name, fm.month, s.uploadedvalue, s.uploadedby, 
       s.uploadedon
from   (
select factory_id, month, 
       min(uploadedvalue) keep (dense_rank last order by uploadedon) as uploadedvalue,
       min(uploadedby)    keep (dense_rank last order by uploadedon) as uploadedby,
       max(uploadedon) as uploadedon
from   updates
group by factory_id, month
) s
partition by (month)
right outer join (select * from factories cross join months) fm  
         on fm.factory_id = s.factory_id
        and fm.month      = s.month
order by month, factory_id
;
```

**Output**:

```
FACTORY_ID  FACTORY_NAME  MONTH  UPLOADEDVALUE  UPLOADEDBY  UPLOADEDON
----------  ------------  -----  -------------  ----------  -------------------
1001        Factory1      01               400  User2       30.11.2016 12.00 PM
1002        Factory2      01            102.12  User1       29.11.2016 07:28 PM
1003        Factory3      01            
1001        Factory1      02            
1002        Factory2      02            
1003        Factory3      02
```

Comment: This is duplicating the records into number of times in the months table due to cross join.

Comment: @Robinclave - No, it is not duplicating anything. In your real-life example, you will likely have data for more than one month, and this is what I tried to illustrate. Of course, in your *inputs* you only had data for one month, so in my output the rows for the second month are all empty, but if you add data for a second month you will see nothing is "duplicated". (Just try it!) Of course, if in a **report** you need data only for one month, you can add a WHERE clause right before ORDER BY (and you may omit the MONTH from the output).